# how to read a file content from tornado http filebody?

Tags: python, http, tornado

My file is like this, but I can't exec the content correctly. I've spent my whole afternoon on this, and still so confused. The main reason is that I don't know what does that [file_obj[0]['body']] looks like.

here is part of my code

```
# user_file  content 
"uid = 'h123456789'"
"data = [something]"
# end of user_file
```

---

```
# code piece

file_obj = req.request.files.get('user_file', None)  

for i in file_obj[0]['body']:
    i.strip('\n')  # I tried comment out this line, still can't work
    exec(i) 

# I failed
```

Can you tell me what does the user_file conentent would looks like in the file_obj body? So that I can figure out the solution maybe. I submitted  it with http form  to tornado.

Really thanks.

Comment: Can I use the for loop like that to file_obj[0]['body']?

Comment: Failed where? Can you post the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
#first file object in request.
file1 = self.request.files['file1'][0]

#where the file content actually placed.
content = file1['body']

#split content into lines, unix line terminals assumed.
lines = content.split(b'\n')

for l in lines:
    #after decoding into strings, you're free to execute them.
    try:
        exec(l.decode())
    except:
        pass
```